# Mongos instance can't connect to Config server replica set

Tags: mongodb

I am deploying a sharded mongodb cluster with the configuration:

> 3 Mongod instances in a replica set
>
> 3 config server instances in a replica set
>
> 1 mongos instance

I am trying to start the mongos instance with the following command but the mongos instance fails to connect. This is the error I get:

```
2020-03-04T00:59:49.312+0000 W NETWORK  [mongosMain] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:49.747+0000 W NETWORK  [monitoring keys for HMAC] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:49.818+0000 W NETWORK  [mongosMain] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:50.254+0000 W NETWORK  [monitoring keys for HMAC] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:50.323+0000 W NETWORK  [mongosMain] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:50.762+0000 W NETWORK  [monitoring keys for HMAC] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:50.829+0000 W NETWORK  [mongosMain] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:51.268+0000 W NETWORK  [monitoring keys for HMAC] Unable to reach primary for set crepset
2020-03-04T00:59:51.268+0000 I NETWORK  [monitoring keys for HMAC] Cannot reach any nodes for set crepset. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1261 checks in a row.
```

I run the following command to start the instance:

`mongos --configdb crepset/host1:27019>,<host2:27019>,<host3:27019> --port 27017 --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongos.log  --keyFile /etc/mongokeyfile --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/MongoAuthCert.pem --sslPEMKeyPassword <pwd>`

I can connect mongo shell to the config server replica set and get the status of the set from the mongos instance. Could someone tell me why I am seeing this error?

Comment: You should normally use a `mongos.conf` file for spawning the `mongos`. You can find out more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/). Then spawn `mongos` like `mongos -f mongos.conf`

Comment: Also did you initiate the replica sets once you spawned them? Seems like `mongos` cannot find the primary for the `crepset` replica set

Comment: I initiated the replica set on the primary node and then added members to it. Yes, it can't find the primary. But when i connect through the mongo shell and run rs.status() I can see the primary and secondary nodes in the replica set: crepset

Comment: Did you initiate the config servers replica set?

Comment: yes. It's up and running

Comment: I am downloading mongos version 3.6 as rpm package which apparently does not include the mongos.conf file. Do you know how can i download this file?

Comment: Check the link in my first comment. You can create your own `mongos.conf` file according to the options mentioned in the link

Comment: also why dont you use `mongo` to connect to `mongos`?